# Losing information When Redirect Item From One Page To Another - Oracle APEX 18

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have in my application a page that is a based on form, and we have another page that is a modal tree.

When we select the node from the modal tree that open from button in page  based form,
we pass between the modal page to the form page, with apex_util.prepare_url , the selected node id.

My issue is when we fill the form and when we set the page items manually, 
and after we send back the select node id, the data that we filled  disappear.

And the only page items that are on the form, is the selected node id.
I understand it happened cause the apex_util.prepare_url and the only item we send to the page based form(selected node id).

Please correct me if im wrong and if its possible to keep on session the items, that when we sent back the 
selected node id, we will not loosing.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Persist variables between page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads)

Comment: @ChrisG there is a way in oracle APEX 18.1 to handle the data that when item returned from another page in link , the all data wil NOT disappear?